# Assign custom string to string attribute in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

So, I have a struct:

```
typedef struct _connection {
    int socket;                 // host-to-client socket id.
    struct sockaddr address;    // address of client. 
    int address_length;         // length of address field.

    std::string user;
    std::string group; 

    int connected;
}
```

and a main code where `conn` is an instance of this struct:

```
char buffer[256];
std::string s = std::string(buffer);
conn->user  = s.substr(0, s.find(' '));
```

However, the last line gives a Segmentation Fault. I know for a fact that `conn`is not null, nor is `s.substr(0, s.find(' '))` null. Is there a rule in struct assignments I'm unaware of?

Comment: Why do you cast this to `const char*`?

Comment: `std::string::substr` returns an `std::string`, not a `const char*`. The `user` member of your `struct` is a C++-style string, not a C-style one. Therefore, the cast to a `const char*` is not necessary. Just do the assignment without it.

Comment: A prime example of why not to use c casts. `substr` returns a `std:: string` and your cast does a reinterpret_cast. Just remove the cast and all will be ok.

Comment: Yes, I apologize. The cast was me trying to solve the problem. It still gives Segmentation Fault without it.

Comment: If that didn't fix it, the problem is probably with the `conn` pointer.

Comment: @TedLyngmo `char buffer[256]`

Comment: Is `buffer` filled with data or left undefined?  The single-argument `std::string` constructor requires a NUL-terminated string as input, and the code in the question doesn't show a NUL-terminated anything.

Comment: Also you don't need to `typedef` struct definitions in C++

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] demonstrating the error in action. The code shown is not enough by itself to diagnose the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct a temporary `std::string` that will be *move assigned* (instead of copied) into `s.user` directly like below. The potentially dangerous creation of `s` from the *not necessarily* null-terminated `buffer` is not needed:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

s.user = std::string(std::begin(buffer),            // create a string from the start
                     std::find(std::begin(buffer),  // find from the start
                               std::end(buffer),    // ... to the end
                               ' '                  // ... and look for space
                              )
                    );
```

This uses the `std::string` constructor that uses *iterators*. The first points to where to start copying and the second iterator points at the end, which is what `std::find` will return.

If no space is found, the whole `buffer` will be used.

Also worth noting: The `typedef` you have is just ignored, so just remove it:

```
struct _connection {
    // ...
};
```

Comment: " The potentially dangerous creation of s from the not necessarily null-terminated buffer"Yes, this is probably the reason, thank you.

Comment: @CHAVE_ You're welcome! If it's not null-terminated as it should, you'll get some 256 `char` usernames  - or perhaps the search for space always saves the day.